# Excel VBA - Reorganize data from multiple columns into new rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data in Excel that I need to reorganize. Here's essentially what I need:

[image: Sample Data]

The data starts from cell A1 ("First Name" is in cell A1) and I have other columns after "Website" too. I don't know much VBA so I would appreciate if someone can provide a full solution to this.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post any methods/formulas you've attempted.  Also, is it possible for "John Carter"'s emails to all be the same, or will they always be different email address?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. I'd suggest something like this: `For Each rngCell in Range("D2:I100") : If rngCell.Value2 <> vbNullString Then`

Comment: Is there only ever going to be a maximum of 6 Email addresses for one person or are we to assume that "Phone", "Website" etc will move across?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sh.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select

For m = 2 To Selection.Row
sh.Range("d" & m & ":" & "i" & m).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Copy
j = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "g").End(xlUp).Row + 1
sh.Range("g" & j).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
sh.Range("a" & m & ":" & "c" & m).Copy
k = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "g").End(xlUp).Row
sh.Range("a" & k & ":" & "c" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
sh.Range("j" & m & ":" & "l" & m).Copy
n = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp).Row + 1
sh.Range("d" & n & ":" & "f" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Next m
End Sub
```

My raw data resides between A1:L1 and result output data reside between a to g column like this... First Name   Last Name   Number of Emails    Phone   Website Other Columns   Mail